# jQuery Camera slider keyboard controls

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the [Camera jQuery slideshow](http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/camera/) on my site, but it lacks being able to control with keyboard which I need.  In their google group someone posted the previous/next commands which work, however I still need the pause/resume keyboard button to work (in my case I'm using the spacebar).  What would I need to enter to have .camera_play also controlled by the spacebar? Is that even possible?

Here is the code that pertains to the problem:

```
  $(document.documentElement).keyup(function (event) {
// handle cursor keys
if (event.keyCode == 37) {//go left
    $('.camera_prev').click();
} else if (event.keyCode == 39) { //go right
    $('.camera_next').click();
} else if(event.keyCode == 32) { // spacebar to stop
    $('.camera_stop').click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing how camera plugin works, you can use the `:visible` selector to click on the currently active action (which may be stop or resume), like this:

```
$(document.documentElement).keyup(function (event) {
   // handle cursor keys
   if (event.keyCode == 37) {//go left
       $('.camera_prev').click();
   } else if (event.keyCode == 39) { //go right
       $('.camera_next').click();
   } else if(event.keyCode == 32) { // spacebar to stop
       $('.camera_stop , .camera_play').filter(':visible').click();
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly.  Ahh, at one point I had both stop and play in there, but didn't have .filter(':visible').click(); .

Answer (score 0):

The documentation doesn't show this, but I dug into the code and it looks like when you click the stop button, it adds a class to the main wrapper called 'paused'. Here's how you can update the your code to handle both pausing and starting with the space bar.

```
$(document.documentElement).keyup(function (event) {
    // handle cursor keys
    if (event.keyCode == 37) {//go left
        $('.camera_prev').click();
    } else if (event.keyCode == 39) { //go right
        $('.camera_next').click();
    } else if(event.keyCode == 32) { // spacebar to stop
        if($('.camera_wrap').hasClass('paused')){  
            $('.camera_play').click();
        }
        else{
            $('.camera_stop').click();
        }
    }
}
```